# How can I return this countNumber to the fragment?

Tags: java, database, fragment, record

public class TestDatabase {

```
public static final String TAG = "TestDatabase";

public static TestDatabase database;

public static String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db";

public static String TABLE_TEST_INFO = "TEST_INFO";

public static int DATABASE_VERSION = 7;

private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

private SQLiteDatabase db;

private Context context;


private TestDatabase(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public static TestDatabase getInstance(Context context){
    if(database == null){
        database = new TestDatabase(context);
    }

    return database;

}

public boolean open(){
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return true;
}

public void close() {
    db.close();
    database = null;
}








private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        String DROP_SQL = "drop table if exists " + TABLE_TEST_INFO;
        try {
            _db.execSQL(DROP_SQL);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
        }

        String CREATE_SQL = "create table " + TABLE_TEST_INFO + "("
                + "  _id INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + "  YEAR INTEGER, "
                + "  MONTH INTEGER, "
                + "  AGE INTEGER, "
                + "  GRADE INTEGER, "
                + "  SCORE INTEGER, "
                + "  CREATE_DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP "
                + ")";

        try {
            _db.execSQL(CREATE_SQL);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        if (oldVersion < 2) {   // version 1

        }

    }

}

public void insertRecord(String year, String month, String age, String grade, String score ) {
    try {
        db.execSQL( "insert into " + TABLE_TEST_INFO + "(YEAR, MONTH, AGE, GRADE, SCORE) values ('" + year + "', '" + month + "', '" + age + "', '" + grade + "', '" + score + "');" );
    } catch(Exception ex) {
    }
}

public ArrayList<TestInfo> selectAll() {
    ArrayList<TestInfo> result = new ArrayList<TestInfo>();




    try {
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select YEAR, MONTH, AGE, GRADE, SCORE from " + TABLE_TEST_INFO, null);
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            cursor.moveToNext();
            String year = cursor.getString(0);
            String month = cursor.getString(1);
            String age = cursor.getString(2);
            String grade = cursor.getString(3);
            String score = cursor.getString(4);
            //String subject = cursor.getString(5);




            TestInfo info = new TestInfo(year, month, age, grade, score);
            result.add(info);
            }
            int countNumber = cursor.getCount(); // Here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        } catch(Exception ex) {
        }
        return result;
  }
```

}

I want to record the number of RECORDS by transferring 'countNumber' to fragment in this code.

```
----------Among the parts of the fragment-------------
practicenumber_textVIew.setText(??+"Number");
------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to put the 'countNumber' value in a question mark in these sentences.
What should I do then?

Comment: You might want to (re)read [ask] and improve on your question. Just dumping a lot of (likely unrelevant) code and a question here isn't going to help much. What did you try? Where and why are you stuck?

Comment: One thing I observed is that you seem to be wondering how to return `countNumber` _and_ `ArrayList<TestInfo>` from `selectAll()`. Given that the returned list seems to contain _all_ elements its size should be equal to `countNumber` so just call `size()` on the returned list. If the size can be different, then you need to use different approaches, e.g. 1) wrap the list and the count in a return object or 2) pass the list as a parameter and fill it in the method (ideally rename the method to reflect that) and only use the count as the return value.